# Reset auto increments with data still in table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Most posts I have seen have been about resetting the auto-increments on empty tables.
I have got a table with data in it that has had old record deleted from it. In the past my search has come up with answers like "leave it it doesnt matter" 
I want to be a neat freak and clean up my tables. What is the best way to do this? should i move everything to a new table and truncate the old one then move it all back? would the auto-increment values move with it or would they start from 1 when i move the data around?

Comment: At least in any real-world scenario where the data was already “live” at some point, this is not being a “neat freak”, this would rather be being a numbskull who endangers the integrity of their data ... An id has one job and one job only - to uniquely identify the record. No more, no less. As soon as you start applying _any other_ criteria (“But it doesn’t look nice …”), you are doing things wrong.

Comment: this particular table is there to have items added and deleted from it. i set the autoincrement to something crazy like int(10) so i wouldnt hit the limit. Resetting the IDs wouldnt affect the way the data is used.

Comment: _“Resetting the IDs wouldnt affect the way the data is used”_ - neither would not resetting the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the auto increment value like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

Comment: thats just resets last auto-increment. ive got records starting at 600 then gaps throughout where parts were deleted. i want to clean it up so it all starts at 1 and is clean with no gaps

Comment: Okay, I was assuming that you inserted some data by mistake and deleted it from the end. As you are describing it I will agree with the comment of @CBroe